# Changing "add to cart" link with custom url in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use WooCommerce but instead of buying from the site, the visitor will be redirected in Amazon. I want to change the "Add to Cart" href attribute with a URL specified in each product as a special attribute. I managed to get this working but the code seems a little bit messy- plus I had to change the plugin code - . Is there a way to make this in a more "proper" way?

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'_product_attributes'  );?>


<a class="btn single_add_to_cart_button button alt" href="<?php echo $meta[0]['amazon_url']['value']?> ">Buy from Amazon</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce has this already set up with the "External/Affiliate Product" setting for your product.

See [this video on YouTube for an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iim_6LSkVFY) or [View Woo's documentation and video](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/managing-products/#section-7)

In short, you put in the product URL after selecting the External/Affiliate Product dropdown option (single product is the default) and then you can customize the Add to cart text.